# Тип для хранения материала предмета

Tags: java, c#, c++, алгоритм

Допустим есть класс `Item` - предмет
И у этого класса есть переменная, которая хранит в себе значение - тип предмета
Это может быть стол, или ключ или что-то еще
И вот возникает потребность узнать что за предмет перед нами? <strike>Всем сразу понятно,</strike> нужно написать геттер
Но вот мне не понятно: лучше хранить в переменной целочисленного типа или же строкового?
Например(Java):

```
private final int ID;
/* куча кода */
ID = 255;
```

Или же

```
private final String TYPE;
/* еще одна куча кода*/
TYPE = "Stone";
```

P.S.: пример кода написан на Java, но он относится не только к этому языку

Comment: Тип предмета по идее - это отдельный класс, а то и множетсво всяких классов с одним абстрактным родителем ItemType. Иначе где-то вам придется написать один большой if, который будет что-то делать с предметом в зависимости от типа. И тип переменной в таком случае не будет иметь абсолютно никакого значения.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Не храните тип(класс) объекта в объекте если вы имеете дело с языком с сильной типизацией. 
Как правило, это ошибка проектирования. Вы можете легко нагуглить русский перевод книги "Скользкие места C++", где подробно описано, почему так делать нельзя - за исключением очень редких случаев - вкратце: накладные расходы, лишний код, ручные проверки, гора ошибок.

Для других языков, думаю, подобные статьи/учебники тоже легко найти.

Поймите, что тип объекта и его значение - это две абсолютно разные концепции.

Полиморфизм придуман как раз для того, чтобы программист не выбирал, например "а какую функцию вызвать, если объект должен двигаться?"

- Камень - не двигается
- Птица - летит
- Курица - (якобы не птица), ходит. но если испугана, подпрыгивает и немножко  летит, и почти всегда летит, если прыгает с высоты.
- Кот - ходит
- Машина - едет
- Мина с детектором движения - взрывается

в языке с сильной типизацией и поддержкой полиморфизма вы просто вызываете
метод `move` и объект сам выполняет свой метод move, а если у него нет такого метода, вы (можете) получить ошибку при компиляции. Без лишних проверок, без лишних ошибок

P.S.
кроме того, в C++ и Java есть свои способы узнать тип объекта:

- для C++  - RTTI  в рантайме или SFINAE на этапе компиляции
- для Java - `someObject.getClass()`

для Java, я так полагаю, вызов  getClass может нести дополнительные накладные расходы в рантайме,  если вы начнете еще и хранить тип отдельным значением, расходы (память/цпу) еще больше возрастут

для C++ использование RTTI всегда несет дополнительные расходы (и еще кучку проблем), и применяется достаточно редко

P.P.S.
если говорить про метапрограммирование, то в C++ с использованием шаблонов/библиотеки в духе boost:hana понятия типа/значения могут слегка размываться, но это совсем другая тема для беседы

P.P.P.S.
если вам неймется и/или очень надо (например, в случае, когда ваши материалы это не какие-то классы, а просто номера текстур), то их надо хранить в константах, доступных языку (для c++ это `define`/`enum`/`enum class`), а не в строковых значениях.

Константы будут обработаны на этапе компиляции, займут в памяти меньше места, и кроме того, вы получите поддержку автодополнения вашей IDE (поскольку она увидит, что константа `MATERIAL_TYPE_CONCRETE` (ака бетон, допустим) присутствует в коде), а строчки будут болтаться туда-сюда со всеми их конструкторами и накладными расходами и без всякой поддержки со стороны IDE

P.P.P.P.S
конкретно к вопросу не относится, но может вам помочь:
если вы делаете игру или нечто похожее, что требует много разнообразных ресурсов, текстур, моделей объектов и т.д., я бы на вашем месте сделал следующее:

- запихиваете все ресурсы в бд (mysql/postgres/sqlite - по ситуации смотрите) допустим в виде записи (айди, имя, тип ресурса, хэш объекта может быть)
- делаете простой веб-редактор или командный скрипт для добавления ресурса  в бд.
- пишете простой скриптик, который генерирует вам заголовочный файл C++ или Java-класс из этой базы данных

это потребует день-два работы, зато профит вы начнете ощущать каждый раз, когда вам не придется руками добавлять файл в код, размещать его в нужном каталоге и т.д.

если для дебаг-режима вы добавите еще и запись в бд по частоте использованя ресурса,сможете например, легким запросом получить статистику, какие ресурсы у вас не используются, или для каких ресурсов слишком мало текстур и т.д.